# Error creating repository in pulumi in GCP using python

Tags: python, github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, pulumi

I am trying to create a google cloud build trigger. This trigger activates upon pushing to a certain repository on a certain branch. The issue is at the step of creating the repository. I already tried

```
cloudbuild_repository = cloudbuildv2.Repository(
    repository_name,
    name=repository_name,
    location="europe-west1",  # Set the location
    parent_connection=github_connection.id,  # Get the parent connection resource ID
    remote_uri=github_repo_uri  # Set the remote URI to the GitHub repository
)
```

It works and all is fine. But If I try to run this in a new stack. It shows an error. Even if I perform a [pulumi refresh](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/cli/commands/pulumi_refresh/), which I understand should perform the following as per the documentation:

> This command compares the current stack’s resource state with the state known to exist in the actual cloud provider. Any such changes are adopted into the current stack

The case I have is that the code creates multiple repositories. some were created by a stack created by a co-worker, some by my stack. but when we merged the code. each one has an error regarding the repos created from the other stack.

I don't know if I am missing some conceptual understanding or if that is expected.